# Python equivalent of ruby's `map.with_index`?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I am trying to recreate some of my ruby code in python(can't wait till lambda supports ruby!!), and I'm running in to an issue on returning the indicies of filter results on an array(I think I am saying that correctly).  Here is some example code:

```
array = [200,100,150,500,25,650,175]
res = filter(lambda x: x < 200, array)
print res
[100, 150, 25, 175]
```

But what I really need it to return the index of each element that matches the filter and get:

```
[1,2,4,6]
```

Is there an easy way to do this in python? I was going to try numpy, but easyinstall went nuts when trying to install it.

Comment: I would consider accepting JulienD's answer, as both he and the other user provided the same answer, (minus minor explanations)but Julien's was first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) which yields tuples containing indices with original values:

```
>>> enumerate(array)
<enumerate object at 0x7f4ad46d0190>
>>> list(enumerate(array))
[(0, 200), (1, 100), (2, 150), (3, 500), (4, 25), (5, 650), (6, 175)]
```

---

combining with [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> array = [200,100,150,500,25,650,175]
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(array) if x < 200]
[1, 2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly it!  I'll mark the answer as accepted when it lets me in 10 minutes.

Comment: quick question:  Is there an easy way to tweak this so it return an array of dicts with index, value?

Comment: @cashman04, You can use dictionary comprehension instead of list comprehension: `{i: x for i, x in enumerate(array) if x < 200}` to get a dictionary

Comment: @cashman04, If you really meant `list of dictionaries`: `[{i: x} for i, x in enumerate(array) if x < 200]`

Comment: Not entirely sure what I meant I guess,. In ruby it would be an array of hashes:  Trying to get it closer to `[{'index': '1', 'value': 100}, {'index': '2', 'value': 150}, etc]` so I can then sort them by the value.

Comment: @cashman04, Then, `[{'index': i, 'value': x} for i, x in enumerate(array) if x < 200]`

Answer (score 6):

Yes

```
[i for i,x in enumerate(array) if x < 200]
```